# Selecting table data to array - Only one row fetched

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to fetch data from a table `EmailList` and place it into an array, which will be passed to the "To:" field of an outlook email message (the script for the email is made). I plan on using the `Join()` function to combine the array into a string as so: `Join(varEmailList, "; ")`.

My Code:

```
Private Sub Propose_Click()

Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
 Dim rstEmails As DAO.Recordset
 Dim varEmails() As Variant
 Dim intRowNum As Integer
 Dim intColNum As Integer

 Set MyDB = CurrentDb
 Set rstEmails = MyDB.OpenRecordset("select email from EmailList", dbOpenSnapshot)

 'Let's retrieve ALL Rows in the rstEmails Recordset
 varEmails = rstEmails.GetRows()

 MsgBox ("Number of Fields Retrieved: " & UBound(varEmails, 1) + 1)

 rstEmails.Close
 Set rstEmails = Nothing

End Sub
```

The issue I am having is that only one record is being found by the code, where there should be at least 10 at a time.

Comment: Try removing `rstEmails.RecordCount` from the `varEmails` call.

Comment: @Gareth Same issue - although it's good to know that wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The `DAO.Recordset.GetRows` method returns no more than one row unless you explicitly tell it to return more.

Ask `GetRows` to retrieve all the rows:

```vb
'Let's retrieve ALL Rows in the rstEmails Recordset
'varEmails = rstEmails.GetRows()
With rstEmails
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
    varEmails = .GetRows(.RecordCount)
    .Close
End With
```

Here is another issue ...

```vb
MsgBox ("Number of Fields Retrieved: " & UBound(varEmails, 1) + 1)
```

The first dimension of that array is the fields --- in this case only one.  The second dimension has the values of those fields:

```vb
MsgBox ("Number of Fields Retrieved: " & UBound(varEmails, 2) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194427.aspx):

> Use the GetRows method to copy records from a Recordset. GetRows returns a two-dimensional array. The first subscript identifies the field and the second identifies the row number.

You actually want the number of items in the 2nd dimension:

```
UBound(varEmails, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you supply instructions to `GetRows` like

```
rs.GetRows(100)
```

but there is an error in your record set such as divide by zero (`#NUM`), and that error is on row 50, only 49 rows will be returned and `GetRows` will silently stop early.