# Method .GetRows returning Empty - Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, datatable

I am trying to create a function to retrieve all the data present in a table to use as an array. However, when I am using the method .GetRows (to get the number of the rows, so I can interact with them) it is returning 0.

Here is the coding I am using:

```
    Option Compare Database

Function ListAllDatainTable(TableName As String) As String
    Dim dbsNorthwind As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim varRecords As Variant
    Dim intNumRows As Integer
    Dim intNumColumns As Integer
    Dim intColumn As Integer
    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim temp As String
    Dim value As String
    
    
    temp = ""
    value = ""
    


Set dbsNorthwind = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & TableName
Set rs = dbsNorthwind.OpenRecordset(strSQL)


varRecords = rs.GetRows()

intNumColumns = UBound(varRecords, 1)
intNumRows = UBound(varRecords, 2)

For intRow = 0 To intNumRows
    temp = varRecords(intRow, 0)
    value = value & "," & temp
Next intRow

ListAllDatainTable = value


rs.Close
dbsNorthwind.Close


Set rs = Nothing
Set dbsNorthwind = Nothing



End Function
```

The variable `intNumRows`, which should show the number of rows, shows 0.

The table I am using has a Single Column, but can have any number of rows.

Thanks for your help!

Regards!

Comment: Maybe try testing for `rs.EOF` before running GetRows ?

Comment: IF .EOF is True, it is confirms that the table is empty, right? But I know that the table is not empty. I would like to understand why the .GetRows is not working

Comment: Well is EOF false then?  Obviously is not working as you expect, so it never harms to check your assumptions.  Or maybe try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670172/selecting-table-data-to-array-only-one-row-fetched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Set rs = dbsNorthwind.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
varRecords = rs.GetRows(rs.RecordCount)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! It worked. Could you explain why do I need to use the MoveLast and First?

Comment: I was going off HansUp's answer in the post i linked above.